# Multiple o365 tenants to single azure ad

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

I want to link multiple O365 tenants into a single azure ad for SSO solution. In a nutshell my application will allow users from multiple O635 tenants to login using their o365 credentials ("Login with O365")
Also once they logged in I will be performing tasks such as calendar sync with my internal application calendar and so on. So Im not looking at just user authentication

Is this possible? if so how?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a [Multi tenant Azure AD app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/). For making graph API calls (e.g. for getting calendar info), you'll need to request the right permissions.

Answer (score 0):

> > Also once they logged in I will be performing tasks such as calendar sync with my internal application calendar and so on

Did ‘my internal application calendar’ mean the calendar in your tenant?

If I understood correctly, we can register two app on the Azure AD. First app is the multiple-tenant app. The other is an single tenant app which used the get the events from your tenant.

You can use the client credential to authenticate this app to avoid require the users on your tenant sign and get the events from your tenant like REST below:

```
GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sp.tech@o365e3w15.onmicrosoft.com/calendarView?startDateTime=2016-05-01T00:00:00&endDateTime=2016-05-26T00:00:00 

authorization: bearer {token}
```